# Is there a way to convert .it files to MIDI?

Tags: midi

Recently I've come across some old .it ([Impulse Tracker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impulse_Tracker)) files. I was able to play them with VLC media player, but I was wondering if I could convert them to MIDI somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found this - not tested it though.

http://www.modplug.com
modplug can open it/mod/xm and save it to midi.

Answer (score 0):

I'v just converted [this MOD](https://modarchive.org/index.php?request=view_by_moduleid&query=56349) (from [Morten "Clyde" Christiansen](http://amp.dascene.net/detail.php?detail=modules&view=1212)) to MIDI in Ubuntu 18.04

1. Download [OpenMPT](https://openmpt.org/download) Windows program. I tried with [`openmpt123`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=openmpt123&searchon=names&suite=cosmic&section=all) without luck.
2. Install [wine](https://www.winehq.org/):

   ```
   sudo apt install wine-stable
   ```
3. Install OpenMPT. On menu: *File >  Export as MIDI*

   [image: screenshot]
4. Install appropriate packages to be able to play MIDI files

   ```
   sudo apt install fluid-soundfont-gm fluid-soundfont-gs
   ```
5. Open the midi file. You can also try with the old classic CLI MIDI player: [timidity](http://timidity.sourceforge.net)

   ```
   xdg-open prelude.mid
   ```

   Audacity also open MIDI files.